# Serial Port Communication missing one byte

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm responsible for creating a HMI which will use the USB port to communicate with the device.

I'm new to C# and WPF, so I started researching a bit and found several questions and topics in this site which helped me achieve the starting point I wanted: I'm able to read and write to the SerialPort class.

To test the device I have a UART that echoes back any message it receives. I have a simple form with a text box, a button and a label. Once the button is clicked it sends the text typed in the box to the device (if no text is entered I have a pre defined array of bytes to test). The label is update anytime the port receives bytes.

The code runs ok for the first message (doesn't matter which), but any message sent after that almost always comes back with missing bytes. I have no clue as to why this is happening, I tried discarding the buffers every time, but to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace LearningSteps
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Comm.xaml
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public partial class Comm : Window
    {
        SerialPort port;
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();

        public delegate void AtualizaCallBack(string message);

        public Comm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //InitializeBackgroundWorker();
            port = new SerialPort("COM4",115200,Parity.None,8,StopBits.One);
            port.RtsEnable = true;
            port.DataReceived +=
            new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recebido);
            port.Open();

        }

        private void Recebido(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            String indata = sp.ReadExisting();

            sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
            sp.DiscardInBuffer();

            my_label.Dispatcher.Invoke(new AtualizaCallBack(this.atualiza),new object[]{indata});

        }

        private void bt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                byte[] vetor = new byte[] { 0x40, 0x45, 0x2B, 0x5C, 0x10 };
                port.DiscardOutBuffer();
                port.Write(vetor, 0, 5);
            }
            else
            {
                port.DiscardOutBuffer();
                port.Write(txt1.Text);
            }
        }

        private void atualiza(string s)
        {
            my_label.Content = s;
        }

    }
}
```

And here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LearningSteps.Comm"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Comm" Height="346" Width="404">
    <Grid Background="#FF9E9E9E">
        <Label x:Name="my_label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="80,200,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" Background="#FFD1D18D" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF1D83BD" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Lalala"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="80,80,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="240" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <Button x:Name="bt" Content="Enviar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="140,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF4084BD" Click="bt_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE6C041"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE8C382" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any ideas of what might be the problem here?

Comment: Your subject says "missing one byte". Your commentary says "missing bytes". Please clarify. Is it always the first byte(s)? Last? You say "almost always". Every time but the first or just usually? The same number of bytes each time?

Comment: I wouldn't ever flush your receive buffer. What if your loopback is sending 10 bytes, but your receive handler is called with the first 5 bytes while the other 5 are being received? You're flushing the buffer and possibly discarding some data. Also, check the number of bytes you actually received and the actual contents in the debugger. Perhaps your baud rate is off by "just a bit" causing a little corruptions and characters that can't display in the control.

Comment: Sorry Bob, got a bit lost while asking the question here. If I keep sending lines w/o spaces it's just the first byte/letter. If I try sending something like "hello world" it can miss more than one byte (got a whole word to vanish once).

It's pretty much a 95% chance of data corruption after the first message.

Comment: I didn't want to flush the buffer for those concerns as well, Steve. But since I ran into a wall I figured I could give it try, but it didn't change anything at all.

The baud rate was specified to me by the hardware crew, and when I test it using Hyper Terminal it works perfectly so I don't think it's off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        sp.DiscardOutBuffer();
        sp.DiscardInBuffer();
```

This is *very* unwise, the port will continue to receive data at the time you call sp.ReadExisting().  At the high baudrate you are using, there are non-zero odds that another byte was received when ReadExisting() returns.  Your DiscardInBuffer() call will destroy it.

Remove **all** calls to DiscardOutBuffer and DiscardInBuffer.  They do *not* flush, they'll only cause random data loss.  They should only ever be used for a protocol reset to purge the driver buffers, you don't have a protocol.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I did that already but the main problem still persists.

Comment: I only know what you did wrong from the question, I cannot possibly guess what you are doing wrong now.  Using ReadExisting() doesn't win any prizes either, that line feed character that the device sends to indicate the end-of-line isn't going to look very good.  Set SerialPort.NewLine to "\n" and use ReadLine().

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans! That did it! I've set the NewLine as you said, also switched to WriteLine and included the 0x0A byte at the end of my array and it runs smoothly now!

Kudos to you, kind sir, I'd +1 if I could!

Answer (score 0):

Serial port communication is subject to data transmission errors. You need to implement some kind of low layer protocol to ensure communication is successful.

For example, you could include a checksum with every data frame that is transmitted. If that checksum doesn't match a checksum on the data received then the receiving application can request that the previous frame be re-sent.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own you could use modbus. [nmodbus - open source library](https://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/)

Comment: Thanks, that will be most helpful

Answer (score 0):

If someone happened to have the same problem, here is the workaround I picked. This is hideous, and does not explain at all the origin of that byte loss (which I had on my project too although using a different approach and no buffer flushing), but it can work as a quickfix.

Simply prepend a control character at the beginning of each message (in my case, I could use `'0'`, but `0x00` or another one could be used as well). On the receiver side, if the message begins with that character, ignore the latter; else, the the control character has been dropped, and the message effectively received is directly the "payload".

So, in pseudo-code (sorry if my pseudo-code is Python), with `'0'` as control character:

```
// Sender
message = "hello"
send("0" + message)

// Receiver
message = read_port()
if message[0] == '0':
    message = message[1:]
```

Please note that this is not a viable solution, but only a hotfix.